# How to cancel select event on Ext.list.Tree in ExtJS 6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm using `Ext.list.Tree` (`xtype: 'treelist'`) component as a navigation tree for the app.

I am trying to catch when a user tries to select a different node and display a warning message before continuing. If a user chooses to stay on the page then I need to cancel the select event so the current tree node is still selected.

The problem is that this component doesn't seem to have `beforeselect` event or anything like that, similar to `Ext.tree.View`. Is there an easy way to manually add it without switching to tree view?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/134p

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: @ardabeyazoglu Added, just a standard tree.

Comment: Why don't you use a treepanel instead of treelist? treepanel has all the listeners you want